# urlopen not timing out: no error is returned

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, urlopen

I am trying to load in this page in my scraper, but whenever I run it, the terminal never completes running. The next line never shows up, and I can't even stop running the line. I have to close the entire terminal and start a new one if I want to continue. I have no idea why this is happening, considering the same code works for most of the other websites I am using. Does anyone know why this is happening, or how I can get around it?

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    
uWF = uReq('https://advisor.morganstanley.com/one-hundred-square-group', timeout=10)
page_html = uWF.read()
uWF.close()
```

The uReq line is the part the code seems to get stuck on. I included "timeout=10" in the line so that I wouldn't have to continuously close and open a new console.

Comment: You could have a network issue somewhere. Possibly as a result of the ssl. Did you get any exceptions

Comment: No, I don't think so. Nothing was returning at all. Not completely positive what you mean by that though.

Comment: Are you using a container or are you running this locally?

Comment: @Sherif I was just running this locally

Answer (score 0):

Try using `requests` module, but set `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}

print(
    requests.get(
        "https://advisor.morganstanley.com/one-hundred-square-group",
        headers=headers,
    ).text
)
```

Prints:

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head>
...
```